# how to run python script/exe file without python?

Tags: python

I have a python code that I wrote, I want to run this code on other computers, and those computers do not have python installed, nor do they have library that I use in the script.

For example script.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel
import sys

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = QMainWindow()
    win.setGeometry(200,200,300,300) 
    win.setWindowTitle("My first window!") 
    
    label = QLabel(win)
    label.setText("my first label")
    label.move(50, 50)  

    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

main()  # make sure to call the function
```

My solution was to convert my script to an exe file with *pyinstaller*, but when I try to run the exe file on other computers, it didn't work there.

```
pyinstaller --onefile -w script.py
```

script.exe file works for my computer, but on another computer that doesn't have python it doesn't work, and also I cant install PyQt5 library on other computers.

Is there a way to run a python script on computers without python installed?

Comment: You don't need to install python or any other dependencies to run executable created using `pyinstaller`, you may want to go through online docs to figure out how to create the exe properly. Also, its suggested not to create a single file i.e. `--onefile` because opening the application takes a long time depending on the size of executable.

Comment: You can also use https://www.portablepython.com/ without strictly speaking installing it.